# How to correctly specify multiple docker-compose.yml files in devcontainer.json

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

An error occurred when starting a container with multiple docker-compose files using the VSCode's Remove-Containers feature like `Open Folder in Container`.

Multiple files are specified as follows.

```
# .devcontainer/devcontainer.json

"dockerComposeFile": [
    "../docker-compose.yml",
    "docker-compose.devcontainer.yml"
]
```

The hierarchy of folders is as follows.

```
│── .devcontainer
│   ├── devcontainer.json
│   └── docker-compose.devcontainer.yml
├── Dockerfile.cpu
├── Dockerfile.tensorboard
├── docker-compose.yml
```

I got the below error on the DevContainer Terminal log.

```
Command failed: docker-compose -f /path/to/project/src/gan/stargan/docker-compose.yml -f /path/to/project/src/gan/stargan/.devcontainer/docker-compose.devcontainer.yml config --services
```

If I specify only docker-compose.yml in the devcontainer.json file, the container will start correctly, but if I do more than one as described above, an error will occur.

How do I correctly specify more than one docker-compose.yml?

here is [the repository](https://github.com/KeisukeShimokawa/papers-challenge/tree/master/src/gan/StarGAN)

---

The reason docker-compose didn't work was that I was trying to launch nvidia-docker, which compose doesn't support, and it was an issue with my compose configuration, not VScode.

Comment: I get the same error :( How did you install compose?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu18.04 and I installed docker-compose following the instructions on the official site.